# How to change a Shopify variant selection container color

Tags: selection, shopify, liquid, variant

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhJY6.png)

I am trying to figure out how to make the selection noticeably darker or a different color than the other options. In the screenshot notice how "Dune" is selected and its border is slightly darker than the other options. How can it be a different color altogether? This is a Shopify page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the css classes corresponding to the checked radio button. 
In my case it is '.single-option-radio input[type='radio']:checked+label'

You can add css to to the corresponding tag in the css files in the asset of your theme. 
The instructions can be found in 
https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization#edit-html-css

In order to get the value of current variant you can use the following documentation on liquid. 
https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product#product-selected_variant.
String of the selected variant can be found using product.selected_variant.option1 if color is the only variant you have in the product.

You will have to use javascript to modify this css every time a new color is clicked.

If you can give the link of your page, suggesting the changes will be simpler.